# ERROR:root:MiniFieldStorage - Issue with Python and Flask running on httpSimpleServer

Tags: python, http, flask

I am running a small Python app with a custom httpSimpleServer to accommodate 'POST' methods.

The App is supposed to capitalise all letters of a string entered into a form and return them.

I get an error in the terminal which I have googled to no avail, What do I need to change to get this app working?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Enter some text</h1>
    <h2>(it will be converted to uppercase)</h2>
    <form action="." method="POST" name="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**flask_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("templates/index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form.index.html
    processed_text = text.upper()
    return processed_text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

**SimpleServer.py**

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

PORT = 8000

class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_GET(self):
    logging.error(self.headers)
    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

def do_POST(self):
    logging.error(self.headers)
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })
    for item in form.list:logging.error(item)
    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


Handler = ServerHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Terminal Error message**

```
ERROR:root:Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3)          
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8000/templates/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: Pycharm-2c79b07b=b4744dcc-07ae-4e39-9d94-06d7a2fcf11c

ERROR:root:MiniFieldStorage('my-form', 'Send')
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2017 22:11:21] "POST /templates/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `SimpleServer.py`:

```
ERROR:root:MiniFieldStorage('my-form', 'Send')
```

is not an error - is is simply logging the content of the submitted form. Because you are calling `logging.error()`, the message is prefixed with "ERROR:root".

You can use `logging.debug()` instead by first adding this line near the top of your file

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

to set the log level, and changing calls from `logging.error()` to `logging.debug()`.

There is also an issue with the HTML form in `index.html`; it has an unnamed field `<input type="text">`. It must be named if you want the browser to submit that field, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="phrase">
```

If you now summit the form you'll see it appear in your logging.

---

Now, turning to the Flask app, this line:

```
text = request.form.index.html
```

is going to cause you problems because that's not how you access the fields in the posted form. Try this instead:

```
text = request.form.get('phrase', '')
```

This will get the value of the field named `"phrase"` from the form (it's a dictionary lookup). In case the field is not set, the value will default to an empty string - this provides some fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code out.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype><html><meta charset="utf-8"><form id="form" method="post">
<label>First Name  </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id= "submit"/></form><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>var API_URL = 'http://' + location.host;$("#submit").click(function(){
var f = $("#firstname").val();
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('firstname', f);
$.ajax({
    url: API_URL,
    type : "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : form_data,
    success : function(result) {
        console.log(result);},
    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
        console.log(xhr, resp, text);
    }})});</script></html>
```

**server.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import json


__author__ = 'Rajshekhar Horatti'
app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def Createdata():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT)
    firstname = request.form['firstname']
    data = firstname.upper()
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```